# Android Navigation - After deeplink navigation to second fragment, open first fragment in the same graph, but from another navigation graph

Tags: android, android-fragments, graph, navigation, deep-linking

In my navigation, I have something like this:

[image: Navigation graph mock image]

1. When I open registrationFragment (in entry_graph) from a deep-link, and finish registration, I am navigated to main_graph (MainFragment).
2. From there, I can access to menuFragment and click on logOut, which calls:

   `MainFragmentDirections.actionMainFragmentToEntryFragment()`
3. It opens the registrationFragment instead of loginFragment. I do not expect that since loginFragment is the home fragment on that graph.

When I have similar navigation but not using deep-links, it works as it should, it opens the first fragment in that graph, but with this deep-link flow, it always opens the fragment that was opened by the deep-link, no mater where it is positioned in the navigation graph.

I have searched for solutions on SO and web, but could not find the same problem anywhere.

I have tried removing it manually from back-stack and similar solutions but I could not succeed, it always opens the fragment that was opened by the deep-link in first place.

I am using navigation version 2.1.0, but tested this flow on the currently latest 2.2.0 and it behaves the same.

Does anybody knows if there is a solution for this navigating flow?

Answer (score 3):

How do navigate in step#2? I tried the same flow and it worked when I used the code described [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-deep-link).

Basically this is the code

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = new NavDeepLinkBuilder(context)
.setGraph(R.navigation.nav_graph)
.setDestination(R.id.android)
.setArguments(args)
.createPendingIntent();
```

As described in the doc, when you navigate using intent, the back-stack is reset, and populated with the *home fragment* of each previous graph.
Just make sure the required back-stack actually described correctly in the nav_graph xml - each *home fragment* opens a new  indent.

Hope it works for you :)

Comment: Hi @Liaz, thanks for answering. 

Sorry I could not answer before, but this approach is not suitable for me as the deep link is called when clicking on a link from e-mail (it is not created in the app itself), and we handle that deep-link solely in navigation xml graph.

Do you know some other approach to this problem?

And btw, we navigate from register fragment in step #2 like from any other fragment using navigation directions:
`RegisterFragmentDirections.actionRegisterFragmentTo...`