# Deeplinks over Navigation Jetpack

Tags: android, deep-linking, android-jetpack, android-navigation

In my application I'm currently using Navigation Jetpack following the single activity approach, only one activity and a bunch of fragments.

The app contains a fixed start destination, Home, then a special scenario for the first time experience.

- Splash -> Onboarding -> Home ( only first time)
- Splash -> Home

I'm trying to setup deeplink navigation but I found a particular scenario and I don't know how to solve it, let me explain:

When I open the app from a deeplink I see the correct screen but I press back I see the splash screen.
What I want is to open the deeplink **after** the splash screen and **over** the Home or Onboarding, for when the user presses back they can continue inside the app.

How I can control the stack in a single activity?

Comment: They only expose the ability to create a pending intent, but to "deep-link to the right destination" you'd have to manually invoke `navController.navigate` until you're supposedly where you think you should be.

Answer (score 0):

is the issue the backstack in the Navigation Jetpack? Or showing the splash screen and then going to the deep link screen?

If the issue is the Navigation see if this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60618015/android-navigation-after-deeplink-navigation-to-second-fragment-open-first-fr/60619057#60619057) assists you.

Basically you need to set a new nested graph and the home screen as the root of that nested graph.

Does that help?